# Trying to Configure pyls through nvim-lspconfig

Tags: neovim, python-language-server

I'm trying to switch from **vscode** to **neovim**. I have `coc.nvim` configured for `pyright` but now `neovim` provides native support for `language-server`. So I tried to configure `python-language-server`. I have installed `pyls` by `pip install python-language-server`. I went through the documentation for `lsp-quickstart`. It says that I just need to add  `neovim/nvim-lspconfig` to my plugins and then add `lua require('lspconfig').pyls.setup{}` to my `init.vim`. After refreshing I'm getting Error:

```
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: attempt to index field 'pyls' (a nil value)
```

I tried googling it but didn't find any relevant answer. Please help me out if you've configured it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hey so it looks like there is a new fork of pyls. I had the same issue and the following worked for me!

See Here:

https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/CONFIG.md#pylsp

And Here:

https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server

Try:

```
pip install 'python-lsp-server[all]'
```

Then in `init.vim` change:

```
lua require('lspconfig').pyls.setup{}
```

to

```
lua require('lspconfig').pylsp.setup{}
```

Note: pyls changes to pylsp

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can install all packages with package manager in Linux, for instance:

```
sudo apt-get install 'python3-pylsp*'
```

Notice * which will install all pylsp packages.